# Good way for experience WPF developer to learn Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I'm a developer with WPF experiences, my next project will use Silverlight. I have read some articles on the internet (almost all msdn and silverlight.net) and I think that they aren't much different. Anyway, I still have questions that I'm not sure.

1. What is different between WPF 4 and Silverlight 4? (I found an [article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107(PandP.20).aspx) but its based on .NET framework 3.5)
2. Are there any resources for learning Silverlight that are good for experience WPF developer?
3. Do I need a book on Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally really like the course posted here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/

I don't know what you intend to develop using Silverlight. But it's a good start if you like to develop business applications using Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

1. WPF has hardware-accelerated full faceted 3D support
2. WPF has direct access to the full .NET framework
3. WPF can take full advantage of the hardware on the system.
4. Silverlight allows you to create a single app that works across browsers, operating systems.
5. You can use Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 development

For Books, I would recommend [Silverlight Recipes](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430224358) and [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Data and Services Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/microsoft-silverlight-4-data-and-services-cookbook/book).